# Large sample size creating significant variables

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, p-value, sample, large-data

I'm currently working with a large sample size (around 400,000 observations) where I did a t-test and the p-value turned out to be less than 0.001 for all variables. This ofcourse is not something that is impossible to observe. However, i became suspicious of it and generated a random variable between 0 and 20 to see. This also resulted in a variable significant at 5%, which is totally weird to me. What test(s) can I use to determine whether this is a valid p-value or whether this happened because the sample size was large?

Although I've followed some statistics, I'm by no means a statistics expert, so please pardon any "newb-ness" evident in my post.

Latex output of my table can be found below. Thanks for the help!

```
             &     I      &     II     &    III     &     IV     &      V      &      VI     &     VII     &     VIII     \\
\midrule
const        & 0.0681***  & 0.2197***  & 0.2319***  & 0.2319***  & 0.2275***   & 0.1179***   & 0.1160***   & 0.1159***    \\
             & (0.0001)   & (0.0005)   & (0.0005)   & (0.0005)   & (0.0005)    & (0.0005)    & (0.0005)    & (0.0005)     \\
passive\_pct & -0.1791*** & -0.0599*** & -0.0540*** & -0.0540*** & -0.0545***  & -0.0743***  & -0.0734***  & -0.0734***   \\
             & (0.0012)   & (0.0012)   & (0.0012)   & (0.0012)   & (0.0012)    & (0.0010)    & (0.0010)    & (0.0010)     \\
log\_mcap    &            & -0.0079*** & -0.0084*** & -0.0084*** & -0.0082***  & -0.0040***  & -0.0039***  & -0.0039***   \\
             &            & (0.0000)   & (0.0000)   & (0.0000)   & (0.0000)    & (0.0000)    & (0.0000)    & (0.0000)     \\
bm           &            &            & -0.0049*** & -0.0049*** & -0.0050***  & -0.0016***  & -0.0016***  & -0.0016***   \\
             &            &            & (0.0001)   & (0.0001)   & (0.0001)    & (0.0001)    & (0.0001)    & (0.0001)     \\
ill          &            &            &            &            & 107.6237*** & -70.0441*** & -78.4087*** & -78.4107***  \\
             &            &            &            &            & (2.7307)    & (2.3192)    & (2.3322)    & (2.3322)     \\
baspread     &            &            &            &            &             & 0.6554***   & 0.5824***   & 0.5824***    \\
             &            &            &            &            &             & (0.0016)    & (0.0028)    & (0.0028)     \\
retvol       &            &            &            &            &             &             & 0.1127***   & 0.1127***    \\
             &            &            &            &            &             &             & (0.0036)    & (0.0036)     \\
random       &            &            &            &            &             &             &             & 0.0000*      \\
             &            &            &            &            &             &             &             & (0.0000)     \\
N            & 403264     & 403264     & 403264     & 403264     & 403264      & 403264      & 403264      & 403264       \\
R2           & 0.05       & 0.24       & 0.25       & 0.25       & 0.25        & 0.48        & 0.48        & 0.48         \\
```

Comment: An irrelevant variable should only be significant at $\alpha$ significance level in $\alpha$ fraction of times, even in large samples. I think you were simply unlucky with your random variable generation. If your repeated it 100 times, you should only find about 5 instances where the variable is significant at 5% level.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I indeed ran it a couple of times again and it resulted to be not significant. Should i be suspicious of all my variables being significant at such at 1% level? And if so, is there a way to adjust my p-value based on the data amount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At $\alpha$ significance level, an irrelevant variable should only be significant in a fraction $\alpha$ of random samples, regardless of the sample size. I think you were simply unlucky with your random variable generation. If your repeated it 100 times, you should only find about 5 instances where the variable is significant at 5% level.

> I indeed ran it a couple of times again and it resulted to be not significant. Should i be suspicious of all my variables being significant at such at 1% level? And if so, is there a way to adjust my p-value based on the data amount?

If your model is well specified, then the $p$-values are to be trusted. With a large sample, your tests have great power, so they are able to distinguish even small coefficients from zero. This is likely what is happening in your sample.

Your main problem might be that you are not interested in the null hypothesis per se. I.e. you are not interested in finding out whether the true coefficients are exactly equal to zero. You might instead be interested in whether the true coefficients are economically significant. For that you should inspect the point estimates (and the admittedly narrow intervals around them) and judge them w.r.t.  the subject-matter knowledge of the phenomenon you are modeling.

Answer (score 1):

*What test(s) can I use to determine whether this is a valid p-value or whether this happened because the sample size was large?*

Nothing.  There are investigations you may be able to perform to determine if your model is bad, but not if the significance is significant.

As sample sizes become very large, Frequentist tests become very sensitive to small departures from your model.  Also, if your null is $\beta=0$, then it is also sensitive to slopes near zero but not actually zero.  If your sample is large enough, it can detect small differences from zero.

What you may be thinking of is the Jeffreys-Lindley Paradox where the Frequentist test falsifies the null when a Bayesian one strongly affirms the null.  You can find a paper on it at [Lindley Paradox.](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/9419/1/LindleyPSA.pdf)

Things you can do is look at graphs of the bivariate plots.  You can also look at the marginal distributions and the relationships among the variables.

It should be noted that if you are setting a level of $\alpha$ such as $\alpha=.01$ then a p-value of $p<.0001$ is not *more* significant than one of $p<.001$.  The "extremeness" does not matter.  It is either in the rejection region, or it is not in the rejection region.

Now, if you are not fixing a cutoff, and you are using a p-value as a measure of the *weight of the evidence* against the null, then there is a difference in weight, but the idea of significance becomes blurry.

Comment: Thank you for the bivariate plots and marginal distribution, will definitely be using that to illustrate that the effect is within the data.